# A bizarre property

Tags: number-theory

Studing some fact about p-adic numbers I read a bizarre property.

A metric space S is called ultrametric when $d(x, y) \le\max\{d(x, z), d(z, y)\} \forall(x,y,z) \in S^3$. Prove that all ball of S admits all any of its points as its center

Comment: Yes Martin R. Thanks you.This question is then to be discarded

Comment: Not only this: any triangle here is isosceles, and any two balls are either disjoint or one is contained in the other one...

Comment: Right, but I din't want to ask for more than one question. Besides of you say, all ball is both open and closed and, more incredible, if a Cauchy sequence don't converge to a point x the distance to x remain constant after certain term.

Comment: I want to say "That solved my problem!" in the notice below but when I click in it nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

Right, it is bizarre. Let $B_{\epsilon}(x) = \{y\in S : d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$, and let $z\in B_{\epsilon}(x)$.

if $y\in B_{\epsilon}(x)$ and $y\neq z$,

then $d(y,z)\leq \max\{d(y,x),d(z,x)\} <\epsilon$.

Thus, $y\in B_{\epsilon}(z)$, so that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset B_{\epsilon}(z)$.

Continuing in this way we can show $B_{\epsilon}(x)=B_{\epsilon}(z)$, giving the property.

Comment: You only consider it bizarre because you have been brainwashed into an archimedian.

Answer (score 0):

Given any $x\in B(c,r)$, we have

$$d(x,c)<r$$

This happens in every metric space. But if $y$ is any other point in the ball,
$$d(x,y)\le\max\{d(x,c),d(y,c)\}<r$$

Then $x$ is another centre for the ball. Since $x$ was no particular point, we conclude that every point in the ball is a center.

Comment: This question has been posted before. See comment of Martin R above. This comment is going to ajotatxe , WSL and others after.